# Flowplayer HTML5 design plugin?

Tags: css, html, flowplayer

is there any plugin available to enhance flowplayer css? I have been asked to work on my designs and create a replica of the youtube player(only designing aspects like play, a button on progress bar) Any informative links for reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery-ui sliders, progress-bar , buttons and many other customizable controls..
Link:
http://jqueryui.com/slider/ - http://jqueryui.com/


You can check the examples it provides for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes flowplayer is very customizable from a design point of view.  The best place to go is to their website, they even have a designer that you can play around with.

Here come the links...

[flowplayer designer](http://flowplayer.org/designer/)

[flowplayer docs - skinning](http://flowplayer.org/docs/skinning.html)